# Random Generator follows special rule

Tags: algorithm, matlab, random

I am creating a random number from a special rule. That rule is defined as:

*The random number generator Rand[X, i, m] in range 0 to 255 that is defined as follows, where X is a non-negative integer, i is a non-negative integer, and m is a positive integer and the value produced is an integer between 0 and m-1. Let V0 and V1 be arrays of 256 entries each, where each entry is a 4-byte unsigned integer*

```
Rand[X, i, m] = (V0[(X + i) % 256] ^ V1[(floor(X/256)+ i) % 256]) % m
```

With

```
V0={251291136, 3952231631, 3370958628, 4070167936, 123631495, 3351110283, 3218676425, 2011642291, 774603218,...}
V1={807385413, 2043073223, 3336749796, 1302105833, 2278607931, 541015020, 1684564270, 372709334, 3508252125,...}
```

Now given *X,i,m*, I want to create a matlab function to make a random number. However, my problem is that, `V0[(X + i) % 256] and V1[(floor(X/256)+ i) % 256]` will return a huge number, so `V0[(X + i) % 256] ^ V1[(floor(X/256)+ i) % 256]` is possible to implement. Note that, random number will return a value in range 0 to 255. I have no idea to implement that problem. Could you suggest to me some way to do it. This is my matlab code

```
function r=RD( X,  i,  m)
    V0=[251291136, 3952231631, 3370958628, 4070167936, 123631495, 3351110283, 3218676425, 2011642291, 774603218, 2402805061, 1004366930, 1843948209, 428891132, 3746331984, 1591258008, 3067016507, 1433388735, 504005498, 2032657933, 3419319784, 2805686246, 3102436986, 3808671154, 2501582075, 3978944421, 246043949, 4016898363, 649743608, 1974987508, 2651273766, 2357956801, 689605112, 715807172, 2722736134, 191939188, 3535520147, 3277019569, 1470435941, 3763101702, 3232409631, 122701163, 3920852693, 782246947, 372121310, 2995604341, 2045698575, 2332962102, 4005368743, 218596347, 3415381967, 4207612806, 861117671, 3676575285, 2581671944, 3312220480, 681232419, 307306866, 4112503940, 1158111502, 709227802, 2724140433, 4201101115, 4215970289, 4048876515, 3031661061, 1909085522, 510985033, 1361682810, 129243379, 3142379587, 2569842483, 3033268270, 1658118006, 932109358, 1982290045, 2983082771, 3007670818, 3448104768, 683749698, 778296777, 1399125101, 1939403708, 1692176003, 3868299200, 1422476658, 593093658, 1878973865, 2526292949, 1591602827, 3986158854, 3964389521, 2695031039, 1942050155, 424618399, 1347204291, 2669179716, 2434425874, 2540801947, 1384069776, 4123580443, 1523670218, 2708475297, 1046771089, 2229796016, 1255426612, 4213663089, 1521339547, 3041843489, 420130494, 10677091, 515623176, 3457502702, 2115821274, 2720124766, 3242576090, 854310108, 425973987, 325832382, 1796851292, 2462744411, 1976681690, 1408671665, 1228817808, 3917210003, 263976645, 2593736473, 2471651269, 4291353919, 650792940, 1191583883, 3046561335, 2466530435, 2545983082, 969168436, 2019348792, 2268075521, 1169345068, 3250240009, 3963499681, 2560755113, 911182396, 760842409, 3569308693, 2687243553, 381854665, 2613828404, 2761078866, 1456668111, 883760091, 3294951678, 1604598575, 1985308198, 1014570543, 2724959607, 3062518035, 3115293053, 138853680, 4160398285, 3322241130, 2068983570, 2247491078, 3669524410, 1575146607, 828029864, 3732001371, 3422026452, 3370954177, 4006626915, 543812220, 1243116171, 3928372514, 2791443445, 4081325272, 2280435605, 885616073, 616452097, 3188863436, 2780382310, 2340014831, 1208439576, 258356309, 3837963200, 2075009450, 3214181212, 3303882142, 880813252, 1355575717, 207231484, 2420803184, 358923368, 1617557768, 3272161958, 1771154147, 2842106362, 1751209208, 1421030790, 658316681, 194065839, 3241510581, 38625260, 301875395, 4176141739, 297312930, 2137802113, 1502984205, 3669376622, 3728477036, 234652930, 2213589897, 2734638932, 1129721478, 3187422815, 2859178611, 3284308411, 3819792700, 3557526733, 451874476, 1740576081, 3592838701, 1709429513, 3702918379, 3533351328, 1641660745, 179350258, 2380520112, 3936163904, 3685256204, 3156252216, 1854258901, 2861641019, 3176611298, 834787554, 331353807, 517858103, 3010168884, 4012642001, 2217188075, 3756943137, 3077882590, 2054995199, 3081443129, 3895398812, 1141097543, 2376261053, 2626898255, 2554703076, 401233789, 1460049922, 678083952, 1064990737, 940909784, 1673396780, 528881783, 1712547446, 3629685652, 1358307511];
    V1=[807385413, 2043073223, 3336749796, 1302105833, 2278607931, 541015020, 1684564270, 372709334, 3508252125, 1768346005, 1270451292, 2603029534, 2049387273, 3891424859, 2152948345, 4114760273, 915180310, 3754787998, 700503826, 2131559305, 1308908630, 224437350, 4065424007, 3638665944, 1679385496, 3431345226, 1779595665, 3068494238, 1424062773, 1033448464, 4050396853, 3302235057, 420600373, 2868446243, 311689386, 259047959, 4057180909, 1575367248, 4151214153, 110249784, 3006865921, 4293710613, 3501256572, 998007483, 499288295, 1205710710, 2997199489, 640417429, 3044194711, 486690751, 2686640734, 2394526209, 2521660077, 49993987, 3843885867, 4201106668, 415906198, 19296841, 2402488407, 2137119134, 1744097284, 579965637, 2037662632, 852173610, 2681403713, 1047144830, 2982173936, 910285038, 4187576520, 2589870048, 989448887, 3292758024, 506322719, 176010738, 1865471968, 2619324712, 564829442, 1996870325, 339697593, 4071072948, 3618966336, 2111320126, 1093955153, 957978696, 892010560, 1854601078, 1873407527, 2498544695, 2694156259, 1927339682, 1650555729, 183933047, 3061444337, 2067387204, 228962564, 3904109414, 1595995433, 1780701372, 2463145963, 307281463, 3237929991, 3852995239, 2398693510, 3754138664, 522074127, 146352474, 4104915256, 3029415884, 3545667983, 332038910, 976628269, 3123492423, 3041418372, 2258059298, 2139377204, 3243642973, 3226247917, 3674004636, 2698992189, 3453843574, 1963216666, 3509855005, 2358481858, 747331248, 1957348676, 1097574450, 2435697214, 3870972145, 1888833893, 2914085525, 4161315584, 1273113343, 3269644828, 3681293816, 412536684, 1156034077, 3823026442, 1066971017, 3598330293, 1979273937, 2079029895, 1195045909, 1071986421, 2712821515, 3377754595, 2184151095, 750918864, 2585729879, 4249895712, 1832579367, 1192240192, 946734366, 31230688, 3174399083, 3549375728, 1642430184, 1904857554, 861877404, 3277825584, 4267074718, 3122860549, 666423581, 644189126, 226475395, 307789415, 1196105631, 3191691839, 782852669, 1608507813, 1847685900, 4069766876, 3931548641, 2526471011, 766865139, 2115084288, 4259411376, 3323683436, 568512177, 3736601419, 1800276898, 4012458395, 1823982, 27980198, 2023839966, 869505096, 431161506, 1024804023, 1853869307, 3393537983, 1500703614, 3019471560, 1351086955, 3096933631, 3034634988, 2544598006, 1230942551, 3362230798, 159984793, 491590373, 3993872886, 3681855622, 903593547, 3535062472, 1799803217, 772984149, 895863112, 1899036275, 4187322100, 101856048, 234650315, 3183125617, 3190039692, 525584357, 1286834489, 455810374, 1869181575, 922673938, 3877430102, 3422391938, 1414347295, 1971054608, 3061798054, 830555096, 2822905141, 167033190, 1079139428, 4210126723, 3593797804, 429192890, 372093950, 1779187770, 3312189287, 204349348, 452421568, 2800540462, 3733109044, 1235082423, 1765319556, 3174729780, 3762994475, 3171962488, 442160826, 198349622, 45942637, 1324086311, 2901868599, 678860040, 3812229107, 19936821, 1119590141, 3640121682, 3545931032, 2102949142, 2828208598, 3603378023, 4135048896];
    a=V0(mod(X+i,256));
    b=V1(mod(floor(X/256)+i,256));
    r=mod(a^b,m); %% Problem in here
```

end

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you must convert it to binary expression. And then take exponentiation

```
a=V0(mod(X+i,256));
b=V1(mod(floor(X/256)+i,256));

a1=zeros(1,32);
b1=zeros(1,32);
c1=zeros(1,32);
%% Convert to binary
a1=dec2bin(a);
b1=dec2bin(b);
A= sscanf(a1,'%1d');
B= sscanf(b1,'%1d');
c1=mod(A+B,2);% Bitwise

i=0;
temp=0;
for j=32:-1:1
    temp= ((c1(j)* 2^ i)+temp); 
    i=i+1;
end
%% Random number
r= mod(temp, m);
```

Comment: It looks like bitwise xor. However, that way is used to take expression of a huge number as the question

Comment: Is this `c1(j)=a1(j) ^ b1(j);` correct? I think that `a1` and `b1` is a string representation of bits. Else, `c1(j)` is always 1 if `a(j)` is one and not otherwise. I am not sure what you try to do, but this looks weird.

Comment: Thank patrik and user8264. Is your solution correct?

Comment: @user8264 Sorry, but I still doubt your solution. You are right that it passes the code without errors. However, I still doubt the code since to try to scan the char array. Also, are you trying to do something similar as the bitwise or? I think that then you may get trouble. 1^1 == 1, 1^0 == 1, 0^0 == 1, 0^1==0. This is not similar behaviour as bitxor. This algorithm seems to be created for items of type `int`  anyway.

Comment: c1=mod(A+B,2); look like the bitxor. Sorry about previous version. I updated before you asking

Comment: @user8264 I still doubt your random number generation I am afraid. The issue now is the bitshift in the end. Random numbers have a property that is called wrap around. This means that when they reaches the maximum value, the bits are wrapped and they start over at 000... again. Floats are trunkated and does not go to zero again.This means that when you bitshift a double you only biasing the output. Completely preventing small numbers from occuring.

Comment: @patrik: Do you try to test with small input value ? My idea based on the bits calculation and ignore the high bit level. So the result look like the approximation.

Comment: I see, that may work, but that is yet to be seen. You should try to do some generation and then plot a cdf or pdf. These should match the criteria for the distribution.

Comment: @patrik: I see. I think the author wants to create a random number follows his rule. It is not exactly uniform random or any kind of random. Hence, the cdf or pdf is not useful in that case